# Execute command when creating new screen session

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen, terminal-multiplexer

With the `screen` command, the `-X` option allows you to execute a command in the specified screen session, but when you try to use it when creating a *new* screen, e.g:

```
screen -dmS -S downloader -X "wget https://google.com"
```

you get the error `No screen session found.`. So it's clear the the `-X` option only works for pre-existing screen sessions.

Is it possible to specify a command to be run on the creation of a *new screen*? If it's not possible in `screen`, is it possible in another multiplexer like `tmux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer, although it was under a different title and the question was slightly different, this does the job:

```
screen -d -S downloader -m wget https://google.com
```

It creates a new screen called `downloader`, detaches it and runs the command.